# How to divide up the constructor in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, initialization

I've glanced at a Java Swing class' code from a NetBeans project and it has an `initComponents()` method in its constructor, as well as an `initializeData()` method.

The `initComponents()` method is auto-generated, however it seems a good practice to me to divide your constructor code between component initialization and component data initialization code.

In the component init code you would initialize layouts, the editable property of text fields, background colors, etc.

In the component data init code you would initialize the text properties, etc.

Can this be extrapolated to a more-or-less general rule for non-NetBeans projects? (I work with Eclipse and the Window Builder plug-in). What would be the best way to divide up that constructor code?

Comment: I think the main benefit of delegating constructor responsibilities to methods is readability. `initializeData()` for example is more readable than a long list of variables. I can see two drawbacks: 1. you will end up having more fields (class variables) 2. you can not declare filed as final if it not explicitly initialized by the constructor.

Comment: @c0der i agree. I couldn't understand the first drawback though, could you please clarify?

Comment: If a variable needs to be used by more than one method you'll have to make it a class variable, or pass a reference to it. If all initialization is done in one method (the constructor) you are likely to have less class variables.